# Java Mockito Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following code

```
public MessageProcessorTest() {
    _logger = mock(Logger.class);
    _context = mock(ExecutionContext.class);

    when(_context.getLogger()).thenReturn(_logger);
    doNothing().when(_logger).log(any(), anyString());

    _mapper = mock(IMapper.class);

    _processor = new MessageProcessor(_mapper, _context);
}

@Test
public void testOutputSourceIsMapped() throws SentenceException
{
    String inputString = "some string";
    when(_mapper.Map(any())).thenReturn(any());

    _inputMessage = new ProcessMessage(inputString, new Date().toString());

    ProcessResult result = _processor.Process(_inputMessage);

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertNotNull(result.GetOriginalMessage());
    assertNotNull(result.OutputMessage);
    assertTrue(result.IsSuccessful);

    Raw rawResult = new Gson().fromJson(result.OutputMessage, Raw.class);

    assertEquals(FeedSources.S.toString(), rawResult.GetSource());
}
```

And I get the following error

```
detailMessage:"\nInvalid use of argument matchers!\n0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:\n-> at com.emsa.hpims.processor.MessageProcessorTest.testOutputSourceIsMappedToSatAis(MessageProcessorTest.java:61)\n\nThis exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:\n    //incorrect:\n    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");\nWhen using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.\nFor example:\n    //correct:\n    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));\n\nFor more info see javadoc for Matchers class.\n"
```

When executing the following line

```
_context.getLogger().log(Level.FINE, "Some log message");
```

I've read a bit about it but i'm not understanding what exactly am I doing wrong. Is anyone able to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely this line:

```
when(_mapper.Map(any())).thenReturn(any());
```

Here, you tell Mockito to return `any()` (which returns a matcher) when `mapper.map()` is invoked with anything.

The whole point with mocking is to allow the user to specify exactly what is returned by mocked methods. You have basically told Mockito to return anything when the method is called, which is not allowed.

What should the method return for you to allow to implement the test case? Replace the second `any()` with that.

Comment: Hum... The thing is I don't really care what it returns, thus the any(). Any idea on how i can achieve this?

Comment: `any()` does not stand for "return anything". It returns `null`, just use that instead. Also using `any()` for this might result in errors with mockito as it can be unable to resolve its own mocking syntax, so just don't use it in this way.

Comment: @FEST If you don't care what is returned, you probably shouldn't mock it at all. It will then return a default value (for example `null` if the mocked method returns a "regular" object, an empty list if it returns a `List`).